# Children over parent with dynamic spacing between them in pure CSS

Tags: css

My css skills are quite low right now and I need to make some hard thing for my website. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

In the picture "parent" div (with width equal to some constant value) might have **any number** (that is the crux of my problem) of children  with some long words in them.

```css
.wrap{
   position: static;
}

.parent{
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
}

.child{
    float: left;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The children must "float" above the parent and the spacing between children shoud be so as to not make loooooong words to overlay above eachover.

I have no Idea how to make it in pure css. 
Is this possible?
[image]

P.S. I want to stress: the children must fly over parent just like in the picture, with some spacing between them. I know "relative absolute" positioning, but this is not enought to make children fly like in the picture.

Comment: Please post the code you currently have (HTML/CSS), even if it looks like the first picture. It will give the community a better sense what you're working with.

Comment: Please add what you know about the parent and children (e.g. do they have a predictable height, is there enough room for the children to sit next to one another, ... etc. All you know.
Secondly: you need to know what you want to happen when it doesn't fit. What if there's not enough space to sit all children on one line, what if the children arenot all the same hight, ... etc. etc. All the edge cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the child elements to be positioned relative and then set their top offset to some negative value, this will pull them up above the parent. To create the spaces between each child you can set the left and right offsets of the first and last child to some value.

See demo below:

```css
/*IGNORE STYLES FROM HERE.....*/

body {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  border: 5px solid navy;
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}

.box {
  background: white;
  border: 5px solid navy;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 40px;
  position: relative;
  top: -100px;
}

/*....UNITL HERE*/

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.box {
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: -100px;
}
.box:first-child {
  left: -50px;
}
.box:last-child {
  right: -50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <h2 class="box__title">Child</h2>
    <p class="box__word">LooooooooooooooongWorrrrrrrrrrd</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <h2 class="box__title">Child</h2>
    <p class="box__word">LooooooooooooooongWorrrrrrrrrrd</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <h2 class="box__title">Child</h2>
    <p class="box__word">LooooooooooooooongWorrrrrrrrrrd</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have no idea how but your: .box:first-child { left: -50px;} is not working in my Chrome setting, but .box:first-child { margin-left: -50px;} WORKS! WHy?

Answer (score 1):

I added a bit of background colours so you can see what's where.
Essentially: I added a children div that simply contains the children and moved that to sit higher than the parent. Inside the "children", the "child"s are floated and have a bit of margin to keep them separated.

But a lot of this depends on assumptions and wishes you have ...

The min-height in there is just there to make sure they don't collapse to nothing, but as I said, a lot depends on what's actually in these in real life.

Position:relative gives the element "position" as well as makes nudging it possible. The "position" is what we're after: it means the children that have absolute position can position relative to it.
The children div then uses position absolute to move its top upwards with top and a negative value (positive value would be down)
To accommodate as many children as you can fit on a line: they're floated inside the children div.
When will this break apart?

- too many child divs to fit on a line
- Unpredictable and uneven height of the child divs -> maybe a solution is to move the bottom of the children div up instead of its top, but again, it's all depending on what you want to happen in each of these cases.

```css
.wrap{
   min-height: 5em;
}

.parent{
    position:relative;
    margin-top: 2em;
    width:100%;
    background-color: orange;
    min-height: 2em;
}

.child{
    float: left;
    background-color: yellow;
    min-height: 1em;
    margin-right: 1em;
}
.children {
   position:absolute;
   top: -1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="children">
      <div class="child">child 1</div>
      <div class="child">child 2</div>
      <div class="child">child 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the position of children to absolute and the parent to relative

```
.parent{position:relative}
.children{position:absolute}
```

Comment: amm. Well, I now how to make childs float above parent, but I don't now how to make them float  LIKE in the picture.

Comment: @coobit And how exactly should they float like in the picture? A styled document rendered in the browser is not like an Adobe Photoshop PSD document, is it? How many pixels in X and Y axis should the elements be offset from parent, and which corner, exactly? What happens when browser window resizes and there isn't enough space to contain the content you are otherwise trying to achieve? You need to be more specific -- there is a dozen solutions to your problem.

Comment: Well, clearly I have misformulated my question.... Sorry. 
The main problem is this: There can be any number of children. All children must float above above the parent, (doesn't metter how high) but what is MUST - children must have some spacing between them and they must be.... aligned with parent (that is parent must be under the center of mass of the group of children)...

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wrap{
  margin-top:200px;
}


.parent{
  position: relative;
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:blue;
  margin:0 auto;
  top:-50px;

}

.child{
  position: relative;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:red;
  margin:0 auto;
  display:inline-block;
  z-index:5;
  margin:20px
}
.containerchid{
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  z-index:5
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">

  <div class="containerchid">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
    <div class="parent"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: There can be ANY number of children. If children count was constant I wouldn't have asked.